the server receives the req but i get an error in the client
The client:
fetch("/signup", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      username:signupthings[0].value,
      email:signupthings[1].value,
      password: signupthings[2].value,
      img: file
    }
  })

the server:
app.post("/signUp", (req, res) => {
   does what it should do
}

error: Proxy error: Could not proxy request /signup from 192.168.1.8:3000 to http://192.168.1.8:3001.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET). sometimes i get the error and sometimes it works but when i get the error i get no response.
i am expecting the problem happens when the client should receive the response.
this is the proxy:   "proxy": "http://192.168.1.8:3001", added in package.json

Hi can  you add  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001", in package.json file

app.post("/signUp  and fetch("/signup" . Express is case sensitive when it comes to routes

i tried making it app.post("/signup and fetch("/signup" but it still does not work and when i try Get method i dont get the error

Why are you posting an img file in the header? That should be posted in the body of the request.

when i try to do i in the body as it should be done i the body is undefined

fixed i was using form so i had to put event.preventdefault
